# Want to use the special value ( * ) for getElementsByTagName()

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've searched and gotten plenty of results on getElementsByTagName when you specify the tag but nothing for my particular question.

In the documentation it says

> **Parameters:**
>
> tagname - The name of the tag to match on. The special value "*"
>   matches all tags. For XML, the tagname parameter is case-sensitive,
>   otherwise it depends on the case-sensitivity of the markup language in
>   use.

My understanding of this is that if I have the parameter set to "setting" it will return all the elements with a setting tag. This works fine, however, both of these statements give me errors, and I don't understand why?

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(*);

NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Am I just not understanding the documentation correctly or?

The first statement gives me a syntax error and the second gives me a NullPointerException

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String path = "path";
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(path);
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("setting");
    String value = null;
    if (nodeList.getLength() > 0 && nodeList.item(0).hasChildNodes()) {  
    for(int x=0, size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
           value = nodeList.item(x).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            System.out.println(value);
    }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: "_give me errors_" You need to be more specific. (The first is obvious - won't compile).

Comment: Apologies. I've edited the Question to include more details

Comment: Jeez, now I look stupid - I've deleted my answer. At which line is the NullPointerException?

Comment: OK, I double checked that and it's made me realise that the NullPointerException is actually at the print inside the if statement. I think it's being cause by me getting all the elements in the xml file but then trying to specify those with "name", and not all of them have that

Answer (score 0):

You are testing that the first element has children, but your code inside the loop assumes that all the elements have children. You need to test that inside the loop.